# Evaluate $\frac{ 1 }{ 1010 \times 2016} + \frac{ 1 }{ 1012 \times 2014} + \frac{ 1 }{ 1014 \times 2012} + \cdots + \frac{ 1 }{ 2016 \times 1010} = ?$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

$$\dfrac{ 1 }{ 1010 \times 2016} + \dfrac{ 1 }{ 1012 \times 2014} + \dfrac{ 1 }{ 1014 \times 2012} + \cdots + \dfrac{ 1 }{ 2016 \times 1010} = ?
$$

---

My attempt so far :
$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{503}\dfrac{1}{(1010+2n)(2016-2n)} =  \dfrac{1}{6052}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{503}\left(\dfrac{1}{n+505} - \dfrac{1}{n-1008}\right)$$

It won't telescope/simplify further. I feel I am in wrong road. Any help ?

Comment: The sum does not seem to simplify unless you accept the use of harmonic numbers.

Comment: if $m=503-n$, then
$$\dfrac{1}{n+505}=-\dfrac{1}{m-1008}$$
So you can still simplify, getting 
$$\dfrac{1}{3026}\sum\limits_{n=505}^{1008}\dfrac{1}{n}$$
But you can't obtain more..

Comment: Oh good to know, thank you :) I thought the same by looking at wolfram result but kept wondering why this was given in telescopic series part of the book

Comment: I was expecting a trick here since the numbers include some suspiciously recent year-numbers...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are almost certainly on the correct road.  We can rewrite this sum as
$$
\frac{1}{6052} \cdot \left(\sum_{n = 0}^{503} \underbrace{\frac 1{n+505}}_{i = n+505} +  \sum_{n = 0}^{503} \underbrace{\frac 1{1008-n}}_{j = 1008-n}\right) =\\
\frac{1}{6052} \cdot \left(\sum_{i = 505}^{1008} \frac 1{i} +  \sum_{j = 505}^{1008} \frac 1{j}\right) = \frac{1}{3026}\sum_{i = 505}^{1008} \frac 1{i}
$$
This doesn't simplify nicely, but it is well approximated by 
$$
\frac 1{3026} \ln\left(\frac{1008}{505}\right)
$$

Answer (score 4):

The answer is
$$\frac{H_{1008}-H_{504}}{3026},$$
where $H_n$'s denote [harmonic numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HarmonicNumber.html). I don't see, however, how this can be simplified further.

Answer (score 3):

First
$$
\frac1{2k(3026-2k)}=\frac1{4\cdot1513}\left(\frac1k+\frac1{1513-k}\right)
$$
So
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=505}^{1008}\frac1{2k(3026-2k)}
&=\frac1{6052}\left(\sum_{k=505}^{1008}\frac1k+\sum_{k=505}^{1008}\frac1{1513-k}\right)\\
&=\frac1{3026}(H_{1008}-H_{504})
\end{align}
$$
Since $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(H_{2n}-H_n)=\log(2)$, we have the approximation
$$
\sum_{k=505}^{1008}\frac1{2k(3026-2k)}\approx\frac{\log(2)}{3026}
$$

---

Evaluating the values above:
$$
\frac1{3026}(H_{1008}-H_{504})=0.000228899998
$$
while
$$
\frac{\log(2)}{3026}=0.000229063840
$$

Answer (score 2):

First, note that each term is duplicated  $$\dfrac{ 1 }{ 1010 \times 2016} + \dfrac{ 1 }{ 1012 \times 2014} + \dfrac{ 1 }{ 1014 \times 2012} + \cdots + \dfrac{ 1 }{ 2016 \times 1010} = \\\dfrac{2}{ 1010 \times 2016}+  \dfrac{ 2 }{ 1012 \times 2014} + \dfrac{ 2 }{ 1014 \times 2012} + \cdots + \dfrac{ 2 }{ 1512 \times 1514}=\\\sum_{i=0}^{251}\frac 2{1513^2-(2i+1)^2}$$  [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum&a=*C.sum-_*Calculator.dflt-&f2=2%2F(1513%5E2-(2k%2B1)%5E2)&f=Sum.sumfunction_2%2F(1513%5E2-(2k%2B1)%5E2)&f3=0&f=Sum.sumlowerlimit%5Cu005f0&f4=251&f=Sum.sumupperlimit2_251&a=*FVarOpt.1-_**-.***Sum.sumvariable---.*--) gets a fraction with huge numbers that is about $0.0002289$

Answer (score 1):

The answers already showed that the expression cannot be more simplified. However, it could be quite accurately approximated since $$S_{m,n}=\sum_{i=m}^n \frac{1}{i}=H_n-H_{m-1}$$ Now, consider that both $m$ and $n$ are large numbers; we can use asymptotic expansions and, at the fourth order, $$S_{m,n}\approx \log \left(\frac{n}{m-1}\right)+\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{(m-1)}\right)-\frac{1}{12} \left(\frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{1}{(m-1)^2}\right)+\frac{1}{120} \left(\frac{1}{n^3}-\frac{1}{(m-1)^3}\right)+\cdots$$ Using your numbers, the above approximation gives $0.6926513948612855559$ while the summation leads to                       $\approx 0.6926513948612855562$